# Exchanging the formats for date in strings

Tags: c#, .net, string, datetime

I have a date in string with this format `"2/11/2013 19:14:00"` (MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS) format and I want to convert it into a string of format like this `11 February 2013 19:14`

How can I do it in most efficient way?

Comment: As a side note, there is no `DD`, `YYYY` and `SS` specifiers. All custom specifiers are case sensitive. And `MM` is for months, `mm` is for minutes. Read: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

If your `2/11/2013 19:14:00` value is a `DateTime`, just format your `DateTime` with [`.ToString()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tfzyc64%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like;

```
dateTimeValue.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If your `2/11/2013 19:14:00` value is `string`, not a `DateTime`, you can parse it to `DateTime` first and then you can format it like;

```
string s = "2/11/2013 19:14:00";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None,
                          out dt))
{
  Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm",
                                 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/M5NyD6)</kbd>.

Comment: ... after you have converted your current string (with DateTime.Parse or DateTime.TryParse) to DateTime type.

Comment: Is it answering above question? ?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Yes, why wouldn't?

Answer (score 1):

First convert your `string` to a `DateTime`:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(oldString, "M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

then convert this `DateTime` to a `string`:

```
string newString = dt.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: You can't parse `2` with `MM` specifier. It should be `M` instead. Also supply an `IFormatProvider` which has `/` as a `DateSeparator` like `InvariantCulture` prevent a parsing error.

Answer (score 0):

If the input date is actually a `string`, the easiest thing to do is convert it to a `DateTime` first:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(oldDateString, "M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Then convert it back to a `string`, as [Soner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27876773/993547) already suggested:

```
string newDateString = d.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```